# How to disable file upload permission and diretory indexing in apache Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat

I have  a webserever [apache tomcat 8] and I want to put some security settings on a desired directory (as we could do it on apache with .htaccess files).
How can I do that?
what kind of file(Extention)  shall I put in the directory?
What would the syntax be like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat does not enable file-uploads by default. If you wanted to allow file uploads, you'd have to enable WebDAV or build upload capabilities into your own application.

Directory indexes are disabled by default. If you wanted to allow directory listings, you'd need to edit your application's `WEB-INF/web.xml` file to define the default servlet and override the default setting for `listings`.

Tomcat doesn't have anything like Apache httpd's `.htaccess` files.

If you have a non-default configuration, perhaps you should post that and you might get a more specific answer.